# stty: standard input: Invalid argument when using pdsh or ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, stty

I want to run a simple script from remote machine. The script contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
print str(os.popen('stty size', 'r').read())
```

If I run it from local machine I get fine output, something like `36 138`. If I try to run it from another machine, I get `<ip>: stty: standard input: Invalid argument` (using ssh ot pdsh).

The problem is I can't change the script that is using the stty command. This is a common script, which I write wrapper to.
Suggestions ?

Comment: Try adding flag to ssh `ssh -t`

Comment: BroSlow- Thanks it works. Is there equivalent for pdsh?

Comment: Sorry, haven't used [tag:pdsh] before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As BroSlow said, `ssh -t` will solve the problem if using `ssh`.

If using `pdsh` via `ssh`, I used the following:

```
export PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="-tt -q"
pdsh -w ${machine_list} -S -R ssh ${cmd}
```

`PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND` is used to append arguments to the ssh command generated by the `pdsh`, as the name hints.